# how to customize hmc message in hybris when an exceptioon is thrown

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

whenever an exception is thrown in hmc, it opens in pop up with object toString during the clone or any other activity.
how to customize error message (generally in pop up) in hmc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this file :
    platform/ext/core/resources/localization/core-locales_en.properties

For example to customize missing attributes message (mandatoryattributesvalidator) add this to one of your customized extension 'resources/localization/myextension-locales_en.properties' (core extension is better) :

```
exception.mandatoryattributesvalidator.missing=My message ({0},{1},{2})
```